# Getting error while uploading a sketch through Ardunio IDE

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently used the Ardunio board and powered with the AVR pocket programmer along with the AVR ISP cable and it worked just fine and no issues were experienced. However now that i switch back to the default method of powering Ardunio board with USB, getting this error while trying to upload the sketch.

There are forums available on Arduino platform but no definitive resolution.

The board is recognized by the IDE.

[image: Board ID Information]

[image: Snap Shot of the ERROR]

Comment: Did you put the bootloader back on after wiping it with the ISP programmer?

Comment: No i didnt. Do i need to put burn the bootlloader through USB cable or through the AVR ISP programmer?

Comment: Through the ISP programmer. The USB cable won't work until you put the bootloader back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the bootloader using your ISP programmer.

Installing a sketch using ISP first wipes the chip clean, and that includes the bootloader. Without the bootloader the USB interface won't be able to communicate with the main MCU.

Comment: I have marked your answer as accepted and it worked ... thanks!!